# In crontab, @reboot is working but regular not working

Tags: cron

I am studying linux on my raspberry pi that installed debian version.

There were no problem, worked perfectly in crontab, but something has occured.

```
 @reboot sudo bash /home/pi/IP_check.sh
 */10 9-24 * * * sudo bash /home/pi/IP_check.sh
```

Shell script has no problem, but don't work at every 10 mins.
There is not any log in /var/log/syslog. It seems perfectly ignored. But @reboot is working, also the filelog exists in /var/log/syslog, but just for the reboot.
I surely checked permission to execute (r-x), tried re-install the crontab but it doesn't fixed anything.

What can I try something for solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That crontab entry is invalid, maximum value for hours is 23, not 24. Hence that line is rejected. You should have gotten an error after adding it.

Comment: Oh my god! I was wrong the common sense! Thank you!